# How to make a C++ program process in background until the computer's shut down?

Tags: c++, windows

- Windows :

  1. Is it possible to make a C++ program executing in background without any display of Console or GUI ? And, How ?
  2. How do I to make it process until the computer's shut down ?
  3. How do I maintain a function executing while this program is active, please?

*IDE : Visual Studio 2013*

Comment: in linux this kind of process is called `daemon` http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_%28computing%29

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Step 1:** If you are using an IDE then during project-creation it will most likely ask 'console-app' vs. 'window-app'. Choose window-app, which means that it will start without opening a console.

[image]
[image]

**Step 2:** Now within the code your IDE probably will have generated some code that makes a Window visible. Remove that code:

[image]

**Your program now runs but is not visible on the task-bar:**.

[image]

**For running your own code you have 2 options.** Which of them is appropriate depends on your situation, but the second one is generally preferred:

- either use one of the generated methods like WinMain to start your own method which should contain a loop and within that loop your code plus a call to Sleep().
- use windows-messages to run some of your code on-demand. (**preferred**)

The program will run until your computer is shut down; then it will no-longer run.

---

A few notes on when to use option 1 vs. option 2:

**Option 2** is what is typically considered better because it works *with* the operating system (Windows), it only executes code when the OS tells it that something changed. **Option 1** on the other hand does not depend on windows messages - sometimes you need this independence. It comes at a price though: your code will probably 'manually' check if something changed, sometimes do something, but most of the time choosing to Sleep(). This is called [->polling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling_%28computer_science%29) btw. so prefer Option 2.

---

**And this is how to modify WndProc** for option-2-apps. Example: make a beep every second.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    int wmId, wmEvent;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;
    switch (message)
    {
    #define IDT_TIMER1 123 // todo find out which numbers are allowed
                           // which depends on windows AND your organization
    case WM_CREATE:
        SetTimer(hWnd, IDT_TIMER1, 1000, (TIMERPROC) NULL);
    break;
    case WM_TIMER: 
        switch (wParam) { 
        case IDT_TIMER1:
            Beep(100,50);
        break;
        }
    break;
    case WM_COMMAND:
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, from where will the program start processing then? There is no main function ? what's about the second and the third questions ?

Comment: Can you please better detail these two options ?

Comment: Note that, at least on Windows, there are some things you need a window for, e.g. displaying an icon in the notification area. So some applications that run completely in the background come with an invisible window for that purpose.

Comment: That's okay, thank you all. _One more question : how to create a new project based on the second option ?_

Comment: @user3278631 thanks. I have also added some information about how to use windows messages for option-2-apps.

Answer (score 4):

For that purpose you need to hide your window.

For console: `ShowWindow (GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE);`

For Win32 project: either do not create window using `CreateWindow` or `CreateWindowEx`, or `ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_HIDE)`

---

Or the best solution, you can create service, [some sample](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/499465/Simple-Windows-Service-in-Cplusplus)

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can hide the window:

```
void main() {
    HWND window;
    AllocConsole();
    window = FindWindowA("ConsoleWindowClass", NULL);
    ShowWindow(window, 0);
    //close program when Esc pressed
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE) & 0x8000) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```